# How to create app store app update notification mechanism using Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

My scenario, I am trying to Implement app update `notification` for my application. I tried `Siren` Pod but It is showing `no module found`. Please provide me a solution or alternative ideas.

Siren Pod

[Siren Link](https://sabintsev.com/Siren/)

Here, i am getting `No Module Found` after pod installation also.

```
Import Siren // No module found
```

Comment: Yes I follwed but it is not supporting. Siren no module name error showing keep on @Rob

Comment: please share your pod file screenshot... OR please check in pod file *use_frameworks!* line is commented or not.

Answer (score 0):

Did you open your `.xcworkspace` or `.xcodeproj`? This error message is one that you’d get if you accidentally opened the `.xcodeproj`.

---

Following the [Siren installation instructions](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren#installation-and-integration) for cocoapods, you’d do something like the following in your “Terminal” window. Specifically, if you hadn’t created the `Podfile` yet:

```
$ cd MyApp
$ pod init
```

And you can edit your `Podfile`, something like:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
  pod 'Siren'
end
```

Then you can do can install your Cocoapods from the “Terminal”:

```
$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing Siren (4.2.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `MyApp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `12.1` on target `MyApp` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Note the warning:

> Please close any current Xcode sessions and use `MyApp.xcworkspace` for this project from now on.

And now open the workspace, not the `.xcodeproj`:

```
$ open MyApp.xcworkspace
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check this. @Rob